# Получить данные из Http сервиса

Tags: android, http, httpclient

Есть Http сервис в локальной сети.
Http сервис в результате отдает строку.

Пишу

```
package com.example.jaroslavh.rest1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void sayHello(View view) throws IOException {
        Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String mybla = sendGet();

                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
                t.setText(mybla);
            }
        });
        httpThread.start();
    }

    private String sendGet() {
        try {
            String mystr = "http://192.168.0.96/veres/hs/our-services/list";
            URL obj = new URL(mystr);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            InputStream response = con.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(response).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

в результате Exeption, в log

> 06-15 03:48:59.250 13304-13411/com.example.jaroslavh.rest1 D/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.96/veres/hs/our-services/list

как получить данные от Http сервера? (Данные могут быть в виде json, string, int, xml)

В данном случаи string.

Comment: Мобильник к локальной сети подключен через wifi?

Comment: да, через вай-фай, но не мобильник, а Android Emulator

Comment: а посмотрите, пожалуйста, int status = con.getResponseCode(); какое значение возвращает? добавьте перед такую строчку перед con.getInputStream();

Comment: int status = con.getResponseCode();
401

а как авторизацию еще добавить?

Answer (score 1):

вариант вместо

```
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)
```

использовать

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() { 
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
           return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()); 
        } 
    });
```

перед открытием соединения

Comment: String encoding = Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
вот тут ошибка и нет подсказок

Comment: String username = "admin";
            int password = 123;
            String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] encoding = Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);


            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

Comment: И все ровно ошибка 401

сейчас вот так выглядит http://paste1c.ru/Yvg

Comment: а если Base64.NO_WRAP вместо default?

Comment: Base64.NO_WRAP  - аналогично 401 ошибка

Comment: А username и пароль верный? вы пробовали делать запрос через браузер через https://www.hurl.it/?

Comment: пароль и пользовтаель верный, перепроверил несколько раз, а сервисом сейчас попробую

Comment: пишет Request canceled от беда, 1С Предприятие http сервис выставил в сеть, а он не хочет отдавать, на сколько я понял

Comment: уже норм
Content-Length: 8
Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 12:08:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
BODY view raw

hello

показало в результате

Comment: сервис отдал успешное подключение но андроид все же с 401

Comment: а ты все поля также заполнили как в `HttpUrlConnection`? я имею ввиду `User-Agent`, `Accept-Charset` и `Authorization`?

Comment: еще вариант вместо `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)` использовать `Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
     }
   });` перед открытием соединения

Comment: да, можете оформить верный ответ, правильно 

 final String username = "admin";
 final String password = "111";

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() { protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()); } });

Comment: я очень благодарен вам за совет и верный ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
 final String username = "admin";
 final String password = "111";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
```

Спасибо [miha_dev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199075/miha-dev)